# Find object with variable amount of attributes (one or more) from a hashmap

Tags: java, reflection, compare

Lets say we have person class :

```
class Person{
long id;
String username;
String password
String firstName;
String lastName;
String address;
String phoneNumber;

// setters and getters..
}
```

And we have a hashmap full of objects of type person `hashMap<String,Person>` with string being the object's username.

I want to way to search for the object with specified attributes **(one or more**), FOR EXAMPLE :

**username:jim54 and address:UK**

or

**firstName: Jimmy with last name : tornabone and address :Poland**

or

**those who lives in UK ( address :UK )**

Without writing ton of overloaded methods..

my method uses reflection to find the mutators of a single attribute  :

```
 Method getter=getDeclaredMethodIgnoreCase(Person.class,"get"+"attribute"); 
 Method setter=getDeclaredMethodIgnoreCase(Person.class,"set"+"attribute");
```

then compares and changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the lookup by username...

Simply do:

```
Map<String,Person> people = new HashMap<>();

Person person = people.get("jim54");
```

This will return only one user, as the essence of any map is that it can hold only one value for one given key.

Now, as to the other attributes, you have no other option than traversing the values of the map in order to find a match.

This can be done with streams, e.g. to find all people with an address containing the `UK` string (ignoring case):

```
List<Person> matching = people.values().stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getAddress().toLowerCase().contains("uk"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And e.g. to find all people whose first name is `John` (ignoring case) and whose last name is `tornabone` (also ignoring case), with an address containing the `Poland` string (ignoring case as well):

```
List<Person> matching = people.values().stream()
    .filter(p -> "John".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName()))
    .filter(p -> "tornabone".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getLastName()))
    .filter(p -> p.getAddress().toLowerCase().contains("poland"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you see, the two searches above differ structurally, as the changes occur on the number of filters being applied and also on the filtering conditions being passed to the `Stream.filter` method.

However, you don't need reflection to solve this in a generic way, that would be a bad design IMO. All you need is a generic way to create predicates based on the search criteria you want to apply. This is quite a broad problem, so I'll only give a hint here.

Suppose you have these couple of generic utility methods in a public class named e.g. `SearchUtils`:

```
public static <T, S> Predicate<T> extractThenFilter(
        Function<T, S> extractor, 
        Predicate<S> condition) {

    return t -> condition.test(extractor.apply(t));
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T>... conditions) {
    return Arrays.stream(conditions)
        .reduce(Predicate::and)
        .orElse(t -> true);
}
```

The first method receives a function that extracts a property from an object and then checks a condition against this property. The second method simply reduces all the given predicates by *and*ing them into a single predicate.

Now you can use the first method as follows:

```
Predicate<Person> condition = SearchUtils.extractThenFilter(
        Person::getAddress, 
        address -> address.toLowerCase().contains("uk"));

List<Person> matching = people.values().stream()
    .filter(condition)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is equivalent to the first search above.

And the following is equivalent to the 2nd search above:

```
Predicate<Person> condition = SearchUtils.and(
        SearchUtils.extractThenFilter(
            Person::getFirstName, 
            str -> "John".equalsIgnoreCase(str)),
        SearchUtils.extractThenFilter(
            Person::getLastName, 
            "tornabone"::equalsIgnoreCase), // just another way
        SearchUtils.extractThenFilter(
            Person::getAddress, 
            str -> str.toLowerCase().contains("poland")));

List<Person> matching = people.values().stream()
    .filter(condition)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As you see, now streaming the values of the map, filtering on the composite condition and collecting to a list is done in the exact same way for both different searches. We have abstracted all the complexity of having different searches into one predicate.

Now, if you had a map that matched attribute names to attribute extractor functions and also a few helper methods that received a string and created different predicates (e.g. one that checks if the given string is lowercase-contained in another string, another one that checks for ignore-case equality, etc), then you would only need to parse the search string and you'd be almost done.

EDIT:

The [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface was introduced in java 8. It's a functional interface, meaning that lambda expressions and method references can be targeted to it.

Here I've used e.g. `Person::getAddress` as a function that transforms an instance of `Person` into its address. When, within the `extractThenFilter` utility method, `extractor.apply(t)` is invoked, what happens is that the `Person.getAddress` method is invoked, with `t` being an instance of the `Person` class. Then, the extracted address from that instance of `Person` is passed to the predicate (the condition). As the extracted address is of type `String`, the give predicate receives this string and checks whether it satisfies the condition or not (following with the same example, it checks whether the extracted address of the instance of the `Person` class lowercase-contains `"uk"`).

You could take a look at [`java.util.function` package's javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and the [java tutorial sections about lambdas and method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for further reference.

Comment: could you provide some reference on using the "function" interface in the generic methods ? i still don't fully understand it

Comment: @user2962142 `java.util.function.Function` was introduced in java 8. It's a functional interface, meaning that lambda expressions and method references can be targeted to it. Here I've used e.g. `Person::getAddress` as a function that transforms an instance of `Person` into its address. You could take a look at [`java.util.function` package's javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and the [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for further reference.

Comment: @user2962142 I've added some explanations. Hope it's clearer now. I recommend you read the tutorial, the javadocs and other questions about function and predicate here on SO.

Comment: thanks alot! thats a great effort from you, learned alot, even though it still doesnt solve the idea of not knowing the property to check, since user provides a string containing the property i.e. "Address" so i cant go like Person::get+"Address" or something, but overall great answer from you!

Comment: @user2962142 You're most welcome! But, you know, going from e.g. `"address"` to `Person::getAddress` is very simple: all you need is a `Map<String, Function<Person, String>>`. You can fill it like this: `map.put("address", Person::getAddress)`, etc. Then, you simply use get on the map: `Function<Person, String> extractor = map.get("address")`